# Socket.io wont emit events

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I started to learning socket.io.
I begin the tutorial with the socket.io website example
I installed all things correctly but I think socket cant emit the event in the index.html 
any one can help

here is my code
index.js

```
    var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(Socket){
    Socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    consloe.log('hi');
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });
});

http.listen(port, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:' + port);
});
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <style>
      * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
      body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
      form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
      form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: .5%; }
      form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
      #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
      #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
      #messages { margin-bottom: 40px }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form action="">
      <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function () {
    var socket = io();  
    $('form').submit(function(){
      socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
      $('#m').val('');
      console.log('sample');
      return false;
    });
    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        console.log('sample');
      $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
    });
  });
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: use socket.io-client on the client side

Comment: I used that you can see in the code

Comment: <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>

Comment: you're serving socket.io from cdn. the version of socket.io on client should match the one used on server.

Comment: the current version is 2.0.3 but you're using 1.2.0 on the client

Comment: try this version: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.3/socket.io.js

Answer (score 0):

You have mistyped `console.log` to `consloe.log` in `Socket.on('chat message')` on server. That's why it is crashing, and not emitting.

Also, use latest version of socket.io on server and browser.

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.3/socket.io.js

Answer (score -1):

please check this as reference  --- 
https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet/#

io.to(room).emit('msg'msg), or elase socket.emit('hello', 'can you hear me?', 1, 2, 'abc');